# Going from Javascript to a rails action

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I currently have a city that someone will enter into the system and I want to go from my javascript action to a rails action so i can get the city.id from the database. For example

my javascript

```
function get_city(city){
   //city comes in like "Washington DC"
}
```

my rails action

```
def return_city_id
  @city = City.find_by_name(params["name"])
  return @city.id
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ajax. You can setup path in `routes.rb` like `find_city_id_by_name?name=Washington DC`. Then you can use jquery to send request.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'find_city_id_by_name',
  data: {'name' : city},
  dataType: 'text',
  success: function(id) {
    alert(id);
  }
});
```

In controller, you'll need to write single id as request response:

```
render :text => id
```

More information:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Although what you ask is definitely doable, querying back-end each time you need to fetch city id by its name sounds like a bad idea to me.  If the name itself come from back-end (for example, you have list of cities for user to choose from), it's better to provide ids together with names (not visible to user, but somewhere in html).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AJAX to call any methods on the server-side.

```
function get_city(city){
    $.getJSON("/ajax/city_id", { "city" : city }, function(data)
    {
        //Do something with data
    });
}
```

`/ajax/city_id` is some action in some controller that returns JSON when you call it.